# Accentuation of problems when posting on Twitter with PHP

Tags: php, post, twitter, error-handling

I made a PHP script to post on Twitter, so far worked everything correctly, there is only a problem when information has posted an accent problems.

The word "Ação" looks like this: A��o

I've tried to use this:

```
<?php header("Content-Type: text/html; charset=ISO-8859-1",true) ?>
<html>
<head>
<title></title>
<meta http-equiv="Content-type" content="text/html; charset=ISO-8859-1" />
</head>
```

I've tried utf-8 but also not solved. Does anyone know how to fix this?

My code:

```
$title_news = "Ação";
$slug = "http://www.sitetest.com/my-title";

$result = $title_news." ".$slug;

require_once 'twitteroauth.php';

define("CONSUMER_KEY", "");
define("CONSUMER_SECRET", "");
define("OAUTH_TOKEN", "");
define("OAUTH_SECRET", "");

$connection = new TwitterOAuth(CONSUMER_KEY, CONSUMER_SECRET, OAUTH_TOKEN, OAUTH_SECRET);
$content = $connection->get('account/verify_credentials');
$connection->post('statuses/update', array('status' => $result));
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You may need to convert the string to a multibyte encoding internally. Maybe this will help:

http://php.net/manual/en/function.mb-convert-encoding.php

Comment: So here it resolved: $title_news = mb_convert_encoding($title_news, "UTF-8"); Thanks!